# Difference between Serialization and saving an object via JDBC to JAVA_OBJECT

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am aware of what Serialization is however I have not found any real practical example describing the latter one (saving an object in a database taking advantage of the JAVA_OBJECT mapping).
Do I have first to serialize the object and then save it to the database?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback downvoter, however feel free to express why do yuo retain so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of MySQL, you don't have to serialize the object first, the driver will do it for you. Just use the `PreparedStatement.setObject` method.

For example, first in MySQL create the table:

```
create table blobs (b blob);
```

Then in a Java program create a prepared statement, set the parameters, and execute:

```
    PreparedStatement preps;
    preps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into blobs (b) values (?)");
    preps.setObject(1, new CustomObject());
    preps.execute();
```

Don't forget that the class of the object that you want to store has to implement the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: I see, however, when java.sql.types.JAVA_OBJECT comes to play?

Comment: By doing as you describe I am using blob not a JAVA_OBJECT field;   the conversion goes like this (JDBC) JAVA_OBJECT to (Java) underlying Java class

Comment: MySQL does not have a JAVA_OBJECT column type. Are you not using MySQL? It does not support the `Types.JAVA_OBJECT` value either.

Comment: Ok you right, to be honest I am studying for the OCPJP7 and I am looking for any possible tricky question related to JDBC.. so let's say mysql had JAVA_OBJECT... would i have to serialize it first or it just take the object as the name let forsee?

Comment: However thanks a lot for your time it's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: They can't ask questions like that; candidates cannot be expected to know how 3rd party JDBC drivers are implemented.

Comment: I heard from people who have already done it that there might be on the topic.. JDBC is in the exam topics.. so just to be sure..

Comment: I cannot find any info related to the use of JAVA_OBJECT not even with other databases.

Comment: Support for JAVA_OBJECT, and any of the other SQL data types, depends on the database and the driver.

Comment: Do you know any db supporting it? I am really curious to see how it works, if it bypass all the drudgery of the other steps would be super comfortable.

Comment: Oracle supposedly supports it. What drudgery?

Comment: well not to serialize each time would be very useful for a programmer who has to save objects into a db on a regular basis;

Comment: Apparently it does not work for oracle neither.[link](http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/10848-how-insert-java-object-oracle-database.html)

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is used to save the state of an object and marshall it to a stream and share it with a remote process. The other process just need to have the same class version to deserialize the stream back to an object.

The problem with the database approach is that you will need to expose the databse even to the remote process. This is generally not done due to various reasons, mainly security.

Comment: I mean how does the JAVA_OBJECT get saved?